# Spark Streaming + Kinesis : Receiver MaxRate is violated

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am calling spark-submit passing maxRate, I have a single kinesis receiver, and batches of 1s

`spark-submit  --conf spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate=10 ....`

however a single batch can greatly exceed the stablished maxRate. i.e: Im getting 300 records.

Am I missing any setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. From poking around in the code, it looks like Kinesis is completely ignoring the `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` configuration.

If you look inside `KinesisReceiver.onStart`, you see:

```
val kinesisClientLibConfiguration =
  new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(checkpointAppName, streamName, awsCredProvider, workerId)
  .withKinesisEndpoint(endpointUrl)
  .withInitialPositionInStream(initialPositionInStream)
  .withTaskBackoffTimeMillis(500)
  .withRegionName(regionName)
```

This constructor ends up calling another constructor which has a lot of default values for the configuration:

```
public KinesisClientLibConfiguration(String applicationName,
        String streamName,
        AWSCredentialsProvider kinesisCredentialsProvider,
        AWSCredentialsProvider dynamoDBCredentialsProvider,
        AWSCredentialsProvider cloudWatchCredentialsProvider,
        String workerId) {
    this(applicationName, streamName, null, DEFAULT_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM, kinesisCredentialsProvider,
            dynamoDBCredentialsProvider, cloudWatchCredentialsProvider, DEFAULT_FAILOVER_TIME_MILLIS, workerId,
            DEFAULT_MAX_RECORDS, DEFAULT_IDLETIME_BETWEEN_READS_MILLIS,
            DEFAULT_DONT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORDS_FOR_EMPTY_RECORD_LIST, DEFAULT_PARENT_SHARD_POLL_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
            DEFAULT_SHARD_SYNC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, DEFAULT_CLEANUP_LEASES_UPON_SHARDS_COMPLETION,
            new ClientConfiguration(), new ClientConfiguration(), new ClientConfiguration(),
            DEFAULT_TASK_BACKOFF_TIME_MILLIS, DEFAULT_METRICS_BUFFER_TIME_MILLIS, DEFAULT_METRICS_MAX_QUEUE_SIZE,
            DEFAULT_VALIDATE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_BEFORE_CHECKPOINTING, null);
}
```

The one you care about is `DEFAULT_MAX_RECORDS` which is constantly set to 10,000 records. There is a method on `KinesisClientLibConfiguration` called `withMaxRecords` that you call to set the actual number of records. This should be an easy fix.

But for now, it seems like the Kinesis receiver is not respecting that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference.

This is a known [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18620) fixed in `Spark 2.2.0` release